# Prestashop - Creating backoffice tab pragmatically from insode a module

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, prestashop

I am writing a prestashop module. And inside the install function  I want to create a Back office tab to administrate my module operations. Is that possible using Prestashop classes and without creating the bad in the database directly ?

Answer (score 5):

Prestashop has got a class for doing this.
This is the Tab class, use the function `add`.

See:

```
$tab = new Tab();
$tab->class_name = 'your_class';
$tab->id_parent = 0;
$tab->module = 'Your module';
$tab->name[(int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))] = $this->l('Module name');

return $tab->add();
```

Answer (score 4):

you don't have to create the admintap file in admin/tab

only download this module and see how it work 
[Prestashop Autoupgrade module](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/administration-tools-prestashop-modules/5496-autoupgrade.html)

it is a standard prestashop module that create new tab for itself

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can give your module its own tab or sub-tab, take a look at the following documentation :

- [Prestashop 1.4](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Creatingthemodule%27sbackofficetab,anditsclass)
- [Prestashop 1.5](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Creatingthemodule%27sbackofficetab,anditsclass)

The only problem is that you have to add files outside your module folder, and add tab manually in back office...

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. It is the adding manually the tab that I wanted to avoid. I want to do it from the code inside the install function. I figured How they are stored in the database I just didn't want to create it directly I wanted to do it in a cleaner way through prestashop's own classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. Create table database your class `object model` and insert your class into table database `tab`.

For example I modify module `mymodule` documentation 1.4 :

```
     public function install()

     {

         if (parent::install() == false OR 

                 !$this-registerHook('leftColumn') OR 

                 !Db::getInstance()-Execute('
                     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'test` (

                         `id_test` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

                         `test` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

                         PRIMARY KEY(`id_test`)

                     ) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' default CHARSET=utf8') OR 

                 !$this-setTab()
             )
             return false;
         return true;
     }

     public function setTab() {
         if (!Db::getInstance()-Execute(
                         "INSERT INTO `"._DB_PREFIX_."tab` 
                             (`class_name`, `position`, `id_parent`) 
                             VALUES ('AdminTest', '10', '1')"
                     )) 
                 return false;

         $id = Db::getInstance()-insert_id();
         $count = (int)Db::getInstance()-getValue('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'lang');

         while ($count  0) {
             if (!Db::getInstance()-Execute(
                         "INSERT INTO `"._DB_PREFIX_."tab_lang` 
                             (`id_tab`, `id_lang`, `name`) 
                             VALUES (".$id.", ".  $count.", 'Test Tab')"
                     )) 
                 return false;

             $count--;
         }

         if (!TabCore::initAccess($id))            
             return false;

         return true;
     }
```

Try modify `install` function and add `setTab` function. You can modify for your module.